# sed - replace multiple lines (a whole block of text)

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have the following text that I'm operating on:

```
... other stuff here..

options { chain_hostnames(off); flush_lines(0); use_dns(no); use_fqdn(no);
          owner("root"); group("log"); perm(0640); stats_freq(0);
          bad_hostname("^gconfd$");
};

... other stuff here..
```

I need to use sed in order to add `log_fifo_size(30000);` as a new line making my text look like:

```
... other stuff here..

options { chain_hostnames(off); flush_lines(0); use_dns(no); use_fqdn(no);
          owner("root"); group("log"); perm(0640); stats_freq(0);
          bad_hostname("^gconfd$");
          log_fifo_size(30000);
};

... other stuff here..
```

I understand HOW regexp work, just not confident enough to use it.
So any explanation of syntax and or any help at all is greatly appreciated!

I've tried the following:

```
$sed -e 's/options.*/TEST/g' syslog.conf
$sed -e '/options.*/ {N; s//TEST/g}' syslog.conf
```

Both of which got me close, but not close enough.

```
sed -e '/options.*/ {N;N; s//options {/g}' syslog.conf
```

This is the closest i've gotten.
But since **i don't know the ammount of rows** between `options {` and `}` this is a bit tricky.

*I've followed countless of guides but I've always had a rough time learning by documentation. I like a good example to follow, so I guess i'm asking if i can get help to create an example out of my situation which i can use to learn the basics and later on the fundamentals of regex/sed.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed '/options {/,/};/ {
   s/};/log_fifo_size(30000);\
&/
   }' YourFile
```

take the section starting with `options {` until `};`
change line `};` with `log_fifo_size(30000);\n};`

it does not align the log... with rest of section but it can be done with some more code

This assume that section is close with a `};` and no `};` ar in the section content

Comment: `sed -e '/options {/,/};/ {s/};/log_fifo_size(30000)\;\n&/}' YourFile` a slight modification of your example works.

Comment: right, just don't forget \n is available in gnu sed but not is all other sed (like on mine aix and sun)

Answer (score 4):

From your example, you are inserting one line, you can use `i`

```
sed '/};/i\          log_fifo_size(30000);'
```

Comment: Guess i should be extremely clear regarding my config then. The syslog.conf includes a lot more both before and after the options { } clause so i guess that won't work on a larger file. However this will work on some other configuration files i need to change in a batch so thank you!

Comment: just take car of the section (it s ok for the given sample of text but certainly part of bigger content)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^options/,/^};/{/};/{x;s/\S.*/log_fifo_size(30000);/;x;H;g};h}' file
```

This works on the `options` part of the file. Copies each line into the hold space and when it encouters the last line, replaces all but the front spaces in the copy of the previous line with the required string. Then appends the last line and prints out the two lines together.